# find the determinant of this matrix $M_{i, j} = 1 + (j - i \pmod {10})$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

find the determinant:

$$\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 2 & 3 & \dots & 10 \\
10 & 1 & 2 & \dots & 9 \\
9 & 10 & 1 &\dots & 8 \\
&&\vdots \\
2 & 3 & 4 & \dots & 1
\end{bmatrix}$$

I tried to do it using A = PUL that the determinant of a matrix equals the determinant of the permutation matrix * U * L.

how Would I get the answer

Comment: Why are you not accepting the answers?

Answer (score 2):

We have that

$$ A=\begin{pmatrix}
    1 & 2 & 3 & \dots  & 9 & 10 \\
    10 & 1 & 2 & \dots  & 8 & 9 \\
    \dots \\
    2 & 3 & 4 & \dots  & 10 & 1 \\
\end{pmatrix} $$

is a [circulant matrix](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CirculantDeterminant.html) then

$$\det(A) 
= \prod_{j=0}^{n-1} (1 + 2 \omega_j + 3 \omega_j^2 + \dots + 10\omega_j^{n-1})=\frac{n(n+1)}2\prod_{j=1}^{n-1}\sum_{k=1}^{n} k\cdot \omega_j^{k-1}=$$

$$=\frac{n(n+1)}2\prod_{j=1}^{n-1}\left(\frac1{\omega_j}\sum_{k=1}^{n} k\cdot \omega_j^{k}\right)=\frac{n(n+1)}2\prod_{j=1}^{n-1}\frac{n\omega_j^{n+1}-n\omega_j^{n}-\omega_j^{n}+1}{(1-\omega_j)^2}=$$
$$=\frac{n^{n}(n+1)}2\prod_{j=1}^{n-1}\frac{-1}{(1-\omega_j)}=(-1)^{n-1}\frac{n^{n-1}(n+1)}{2}$$

where we have used the results indicated here

- [The sum of k times the kth power of a is given analytically by?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1697497/505767)
- [Simplification of product of complex numbers](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/376781/505767)

Comment: how I can apply it on the matrix I asked?

Comment: @SyrianInshadTarab I've added more details.